# Permuation in a loop on Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, permutation

I am trying to write a code that reshapes my data (35x2) 10000 times. Here is my code for this

```
N = 35;
reshape(table1(randperm(2*N)),N,2);
```

In each iteration (there is going to be 10000) the mean difference between the randomly generated groups is needed. However, I couldn't figure out a way to do so.

```
for i = 1:10000
   permutatedvers(i) = reshape(i)(table1(randperm(2*N)),N,2);
end
```

So I tried these kinds of codes but I am getting errors. How can I implement this in a loop?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Why are you doing `reshape(i)`? Which are the groups you generate?

Comment: @CrisLuengo "()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.' this was the error. I did reshape(i) since I wanted to save all reshaped data but that was not the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a solution and want to share with you just in case anyone needs it in the future.

Rather than using a for loop, I decided to go with while loop.

```
N=length(table1)
ii=1;
while (ii<10001)

t1perm= reshape(table1(randperm(2*N)),N,2);
t1permA=t1perm(:,1); %groupA
t1permB=t1perm(:,2); %groupB
meandif(ii)= mean(t1permA)-mean(t1permB);  %meandif gives us a 1x10000 matrix

ii= ii+1;
end
```

Feel free to criticize and update my code. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `for ii = 1:10000` there instead of `while`, there's no difference except it's easier to read. If you add `meandif=zeros(10000,1)` before the loop, your code will be much faster (this is called pre-allocation).